# How to set package version

Tags: java, manifest

This is the `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: peter
Name: foo/
Implementation-Version: foo1
Name: bar/
Implementation-Version: bar1
```

This are the Classes

```
package foo;
public class FooTest {
}

package bar;
public class BarTest {
}

package test;
public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println(FooTest.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion());
        System.out.println(BarTest.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion());
    }
}
```

But it prints

```
bar1
bar1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solved

I missed newlines!

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: peter
Name: foo/
Implementation-Version: foo1
Name: bar/
Implementation-Version: bar1
```

was wrong

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: peter

Name: foo/
Implementation-Version: foo1

Name: bar/
Implementation-Version: bar1
```

Was right!

Thanks to AurA anyway.

Comment: I rechecked the docs, they actually mentioned it as a warning  ...... (was not sure you were doing for multiple packages by appending )....Warning: The text file must end with a new line or carriage return. The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or carriage return.

Comment: This warning missing a empty line as last line, this is a different problem. Dont be confused ;D

Answer (score 3):

You might need to set ClassLoader Additions as follows

**1.5.7 java.lang.ClassLoader Additions**

In order to support Packages the classloader is extended to keep track of the mapping from classes to packages and to allow classloaders to define the Package instances for the classes they load. The additional methods are defined to allow subclasses to define packages in this classloader to allow the Package implementation to get information about packages defined by this classloader.

The java.lang.Package implementation needs to identify the current classloader in order to call it from system code.

```
package java.lang;
public class ClassLoader {      
        ...     
        // Return the non-null classloader of callers   
        public static ClassLoader currentClassLoader(); 
        // Define a Package     
        protected Package(String pkgname,                                       
                        String spectitle, String specversion,                                   
                        String specvendor,      String impltitle,                                       
                        String implversion, String implvendor); 
}
```

The currentClassLoader method is used to find the current ClassLoader even if called from a system class. When called from a classloader loaded class it will return the equivalent of this.getClass().getClassLoader(). It’s behavior is identical to the current SecurityManager.currentClassLoader method but is public.

The protected access definePackage method is used by subclasses to define the packages of the classes it is loading. Packages with a given name may only be defined once and must be defined before the first class of that package is loaded. The classloader should supply the versioning attributes from the manifest if they are available.

You can use the following example for versioning

```
Name: java/util/
Specification-Title: Java Utility Classes
Specification-Version: 1.2
Specification-Vendor: Example Tech, Inc.
Implementation-Title: java.util
Implementation-Version: build57
Implementation-Vendor: Example Tech, Inc.
```

You can refer standard documentation for package versioning at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/packageman.html

Create a jar and then try to access

```
jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt MyPackage/*.class
```

The API to access it is explained as https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/versioning/spec/versioning2.html#wp89936

Comment: you can also refer another tutorial that explains the same http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074257/core-java/accessing-package-version-information-in-java-code.html